# Namespace Pattern Not Working?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Why does the following code complain that `Model` is undefined?

```
// models/person.js

Model = Model || {}; // ReferenceError: Model is not defined.

_.extend(Model, {
  Person: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
});

var adam = new Model.Person("Adam");
```

Comment: What happens if you add `var` to the line: `var Model = Model || {};`?

Comment: Well, then it is not exported and `Model` will be empty in any other file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Akhlesh answer.

I create a file defining `share`:

```
// lib/_share.js

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  share = window;
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  share = global;
}
```

And then this works:

```
// models/person.js

Model = share.Model || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs in strict mode.

Try this:

```
var Model;
Model = Model || {};
```

the documentation on strict mode: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode#Converting_mistakes_into_errors

Comment: Using this version `Model` is empty for other files.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should check for Model as window's property or use var.

```
  Model = window.Model || {};
```

OR

```
  var Model = Model || {};
```